# Eevee one light creats multiple shadows

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have one light source and it creats 4 shadows in Eevee. The light is in the back of the model so, where are the others coming from? And there is one that is only the shadow of the hair and not the rest of the body and dress, why?

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10bvaUBwSa48Ei6XiOesCCupR6p8CtqT9?usp=sharing This ist most likey without textures since they are from differeten places on my PC and I could not add them in one folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eevee doesn't have the accuracy of Cycles regardings lights, here the problem probably has to do with the light *Angle* and the render *Sampling* values, decrease the *Angle* and increase the *Sampling* and the shadow should be correct.